# Flutter ListView.builder() is loading all items at once

Tags: flutter

I have a ListView I'm initializing with `ListView.builder()` and it seems to be loading all items at once. This is the code:

```
ListView.builder(
  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    if (index == length) {
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)).then((value) {
        setState(() => length += 10);
      });
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }

    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
      child: Text(index.toString()),
    );
  },
  itemCount: length + 1,
)
```

This ListView is wrapped in another ListView. I'm trying to make a network call to load more items once I hit the bottom of the list, but it just gets called over and over again even when I haven't scrolled to the bottom. Is this because I have it nested in a second ListView?

Comment: It's because you have `shrinkWrap: true` in your `ListView`. If you're using nested `ListView` and the child list view is not small enough then you should use `CustomScrollView`.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad I believe you -- I actually rewrote this code now to use only one ListView -- But do you have any idea why `shrinkWrap: true` has that effect?

Comment: @Cory Swainston When shrinkWrap is set to true, the ListView will size itself based on the size of its contents, rather than the available space in its parent. If you set shrinkWrap to true in combination with ListView.builder, the ListView will be forced to measure the size of all items in your list, and that's why you see all the items loaded at once.

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from `shrinkWrap: true`.
Set it to false so it won't wait for all the item to be loaded to display them.